# Recommended way for running applications per Service Fabric node

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

Can i know what the best practice for running applications on a service fabric node, Is it one service per node or multiple services per node? Let me know any advantages or disadvantages if there are any.

Answer (score 1):

One of the goals/features of using ASF is to run many (micro)services on your nodes, to make efficient use of all the system resources.

> Deploy applications at higher density than virtual machines, deploying
>   hundreds or thousands of applications per machine.

Read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-overview).